# remove "learning" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the "learning" tag which only has [5 questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) at the time of writing. However, as I checked none of these questions are suitable to https://unix.stackexchange.com when knowing that asking for learning materials is off-topic; Can we request for deletion of this [learning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag alongside deleting those questions too?

Comment: Given that the newest [tag:learning] question is over 6 years old and the oldest is over 11 years old, is there anything worth keeping? If so, what do we think about moving the content here, to Meta?

Comment: Separately, if/when the tag is emptied, we can request that it be blocked from future questions, if that's what the community would like. (It seems like a good idea to me)

Comment: @JeffSchaller αғsнιη suggested deleting the questions, in chat. Most are already closed anyway, but I didn't feel comfortable deleting posts unilaterally without community input. So I asked αғsнιη to open this discussion here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller we just kill a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/687019/72456) with this tag and that was the start of this request to remove "learning" tag